# Fonts behave strangely inside SVG foreignObject

Tags: html, svg, dom, foreignobject

Observe the following example:

https://codepen.io/gamepro5/pen/NWYjaae

```
  font-family: TF2 Secondary, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: pre-line;
```

Both of these DOM nodes are identical. I put all the DOM note inside a foreign object, and for some reason the one inside the foreign object has different font behavior causing it to wrap more. It seems like the width of the characters are ever so slightly larger.[image]
Is this just a bug with chrome that is out of my control? I see no reason why this would happen.

Comment: Observation: you have repeated id-s. Also I see your text is all just span-s in a div instead of a proper markup.Please can you fix this and maybe simplify the code?

Comment: I have repeated ids because I use query selector based on the node. This isn't relevant.

Comment: [The id attribute assigns a unique identifier to an element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) Use clases if you need to select many of them

Comment: Again, this isn't relevant. If you use query selector for an ID on a specific node, it will find the tag that is somewhere in that node's children. It helps with writing generalized code.